# Does oracle database start new job (from 'Scheduler') before last job (this same) is finished?

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduling, jobs

What happens if oracle database starts job(from 'Scheduler') before last job(this same) finishes? Does oracle add it to a stack or finally stops?

Comment: Hi @the_kaba: I fixed some wording in your question, except for what I wasn't sure about. Not sure what you meant by "stops" so if you can clarify, it will improve the question, however, the answer is still the same, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is smart enough to know not to start a new job instance before the previous job is finished.

From the Oracle docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/scheduse.htm

**Setting the Repeat Interval**

> ...
>   Immediately after a job is started, the repeat_interval is evaluated to determine the next scheduled execution time of the job. It is possible that the next scheduled execution time arrives while the job is still running. A new instance of the job, however, will not be started until the current one completes.